# How to run vi from Symfony Process?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-process

I have the following code:

```
        $process = new Process('vi');

        try {
            $process->setPty(true);
            $process->mustRun(function ($type, $buffer) {
                echo $buffer;
            });
            //echo $process->getOutput();
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

However, it dies for me with the following info:

```
The command "vi" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: [path]

Output:
================
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.


Error Output:
================
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

**UPDATE**

Seems it was not clear for some people what I'm going to do. I will explain. This script is being run in console. The same thing works via passthru (although Vim still warns about the output). I want to have an interactive process that will allow users to modify some file before its sent somewhere. I do not want to implement my own editor and that's why I want them to use vi. vi is available on my server (it is clearly visible from the output I provided).

Comment: Well, are you certain that you can execute vi through php? (At least if you're talking about the linux text editor)

Comment: I am certain. It is possible to execute it using passthru(). My aim is to run an interactive process in which a user will be given a possibility to modify a file that will be sent somewhere after his modifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I was given a proper answer: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19528

Basically, I had to use `$process->setTty(true)`. So, the full example will be:

```
    $process = new Process('vi');

    try {
        $process->setTty(true);
        $process->mustRun(function ($type, $buffer) {
            echo $buffer;
        });
    } catch (ProcessFailedException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a better replacement than `echo`: `fwrite($type === Process::OUT ? STDOUT : STDERR, $buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes complete sense by the way..

My thoughts are:

- You get a Exit Code: 1  --> Which means the file name to edit wasn't
  specified. Although I could be wrong.
- It shows "Working directory:
  [path]". Which tells me, maybe the path is missing.
- Also, I don't know which user (on the system) runs the Symfony Process Component.

So maybe try:

```
$process = new Process('vi /tmp/temp.file');
```

Use /tmp because anyone should have access, also possible a web folder that is writable. Another thought, is to run the process with sudo and specify the user vimrc:

```
$process = new Process('sudo vim -u ~user/.vimrc /tmp/temp.file');
```

But then you might need to pass input (like sudo password):

```
$process->setInput('someSudoPassword');
```

But who's sudo password I don't know. Again, I'm not sure which user runs the Process Component.

These are just some thoughts, and I'm not certain if it solves anything but I hope it might help you, or even help to think about another way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. `vi` can be run without specifying the path or filename. `[path]` here was just my local directory that was irrelevant to the question, so I skipped it. I also tried that under root, so `sudo` is not the case here.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you want to do this? vi is something that is controlled by keyboard. If you need to, you might need to check the full path and if php/symfony has access to this path. Probably your php script does not have access to this script, and the web server (I assume you're talking about a web application here) might not be allowed to start a login shell at the server anywhere. Would be great if you could provide more details about your goal + environment.

If you just want to edit / manipulate the file, the sed command might be an option. Or open/manipulate the file directly with php might be even better.

Comment: My aim is to run an interactive console process in which a user will be given a possibility to modify a file that will be sent somewhere after his modifications. And I do not have a web server at all. PHP has access to vi (for sure, as passthru works). It is allowed to start login shell, since I am running it from the console.

Comment: @DenisV You may want to check if there is an `EDITOR` environment variable set and use that instead if it is set. That way if a user has configured their default cli editor to be `nano`, `emacs`, `vi`, `vim`, `neovim`, or something else, it will work. If `EDITOR` is not set, you can of course assume they have `vi` as a default.

Comment: @Paulpro yes, thank you for your advice. In fact, this was the next thing I was going to do, but without being able to run `vi`, this was making no sense. Anyway, thank you. :)